# Detect if a file is an audio file in PHP without mime type

Tags: php, apache, file, audio

I am allowing users to upload files to my server, so I need to detect if a file is an audio file. I attempted to check based on the MIME type using `mime_content_type($path)` but often times it returns `application/octet-stream`. If it were an image I could use `getimagesize()` so is there an equivalent for audio files?

Answer (score 0):

what if you open the file directly to get the mime type

```
function check_file_is_audio( $tmp ) 
{
    $allowed = array(
        'audio/mpeg', 'audio/x-mpeg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/x-mpeg-3', 'audio/aiff', 
        'audio/mid', 'audio/x-aiff', 'audio/x-mpequrl','audio/midi', 'audio/x-mid', 
        'audio/x-midi','audio/wav','audio/x-wav','audio/xm','audio/x-aac','audio/basic',
        'audio/flac','audio/mp4','audio/x-matroska','audio/ogg','audio/s3m','audio/x-ms-wax',
        'audio/xm'
    );

    // check REAL MIME type
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $type = finfo_file($finfo, $tmp );
    finfo_close($finfo);

    // check to see if REAL MIME type is inside $allowed array
    if( in_array($type, $allowed) ) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 0):

Mp3 data detection is a wierd thing. There is a serious tradeof to be made between reading/processing alot of data or just looking for certain values at specified locations.

As far as mime-type detection goes i think [correct me if i am wrong] `application/octet-stream` is the default fallback type.

if you want a quick and dirty but performant solution i sugest just using the file extension `*.mp3` to determine it's type.

If the reliabilty of this functionality is crucial [higher priority than performance]
you can use a library like ffprobe [from ffmpeg].